# Making an executable python program with Snap7 for PLCs

Tags: python, py2exe, plc

I've been trying to make a program in python using [Snap7](http://snap7.sourceforge.net/), but now I want it to make an executable of it. I used py2exe to make the *.exe file and run it on Windows without python installed. However, everytime I try to open the application, the cmd window show me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sniffer.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "snap7\client.pyc", line 34, in __init__
  File "snap7\common.pyc", line 54, in load_library
  File "snap7\common.pyc", line 47, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.pyc", line 440, in LoadLibrary
  File "ctypes\__init__.pyc", line 362, in __init__
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with the *.dll files that comes with the SNAP7 library. I replaced the files with the 32-bit version of it and it works now.